# Can you GROUP BY with a CASE WHEN THEN alias name?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

I have a SELECT statement being calculated from a CASE WHEN THEN state (or could use multiple IF statements) aliased as 'Length', and I need to correctly GROUP the results together. The SELECT seems to be working, but the group groups them wrong. Here is my statement:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 30 THEN '<1 Month'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 90 THEN '1 - 2 Months'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 210 THEN '3 - 4 Months'
    ELSE '>4 Months' END AS 'Length', 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(person.ID)) AS 'COUNT'
FROM person
    INNER JOIN opportunity AS o
    INNER JOIN Organization AS org
    ON person.EntityID = o.id 
        AND O.OrganizationID = Org.ID
WHERE person.TitleID = 2
    AND o.bID = 1
GROUP BY 'Length'
ORDER BY 'Length' ASC;
```

This groups all results into '3 - 4 Months' which isn't right..

Comment: It isn't right cause enclosed with wrong quotes. Use backticks instead

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to use the whole `CASE` statement in the `GROUP BY` clause if you don't wrapped it in a subquery.

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 30 THEN '<1 Month'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 90 THEN '1 - 2 Months'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 210 THEN '3 - 4 Months'
            ELSE '>4 Months' 
        END AS `Length`, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(person.ID)) AS `COUNT`
FROM    person
        INNER JOIN opportunity AS o
            ON person.EntityID = o.id
        INNER JOIN Organization AS org
            ON o.OrganizationID = Org.ID
WHERE   person.TitleID = 2
        AND o.bID = 1
GROUP   BY  CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 30 THEN '<1 Month'
                WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 90 THEN '1 - 2 Months'
                WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 210 THEN '3 - 4 Months'
                ELSE '>4 Months' 
            END
ORDER   BY Length ASC;
```

Remove also the single quotes around the column name in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Are you able to ORDER BY 'Length' using something like... ORDER BY FIELD('Length', '<1 Month', '1 - 2 Months', '3 - 4 Months', '>4 Months')

Comment: @Phil when you wrap something with single quotes, it because a literal string - *not an identifier*. and using `ALIAS` in `ORDER BY` clause is fine because the in the `Order of SQL Operator` `ORDER BY` is the last to be executed.

Comment: You're awesome. Though my ORDER BY FIELD('Length',...) isn't working at all

Comment: remove the single quotes around the column. `ORDER BY FIELD(Length,...)`

Comment: In my case there is lot of case statements so I would not like to recalculate the value of DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate), is there any way to keep it in a variable like `@diff:=DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate)` then use @diff for every rows.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with exactly the same problem and here is the solution I came up with:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 30 THEN '<1 Month'
WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 90 THEN '1 - 2 Months'
WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 210 THEN '3 - 4 Months'
ELSE '>4 Months' END AS `Length`, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(person.ID)) AS `COUNT`
FROM person
INNER JOIN opportunity AS o
INNER JOIN Organization AS org
ON person.EntityID = o.id 
    AND O.OrganizationID = Org.ID
WHERE person.TitleID = 2
AND o.bID = 1
GROUP BY `Length`
ORDER BY `Length` ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group-by on statements from select by referencing them like this. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7392730/2664585).

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 30 THEN '<1 Month'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 90 THEN '1 - 2 Months'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(o.EndDate, o.StartDate) < 210 THEN '3 - 4 Months'
    ELSE '>4 Months' END AS 'Length', 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(person.ID)) AS 'COUNT'
FROM person
    INNER JOIN opportunity AS o
    INNER JOIN Organization AS org
    ON person.EntityID = o.id 
        AND O.OrganizationID = Org.ID
WHERE person.TitleID = 2
AND o.bID = 1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```