# mysql group by ignore null

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table given below

```
id     album_id   album_name
----   ---------  -----------
1          5         test1
2          5         test1
3          6         test3
4          6         test3
5          NULL      test4
6          NULL      test4
```

I want to write a query using group by album_id , it will give below result

```
id     album_id   album_name
----   ---------  -----------
1          5         test1
3          6         test3
5          NULL      test4
6          NULL      test4
```

I have tried but its grouping NULL column also, I want all the rows which are NULL and group by album_id which are not null.

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096344/can-you-group-by-with-a-case-when-then-alias-name) - but don't work for me

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id,
       album_id,
       album_name
FROM T
GROUP BY COALESCE(album_id, id), album_name
ORDER BY album_name;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad01/4)**

So when `album_id` IS NULL then you also group by `id` ensuring that all rows are returned where `album_id` is null.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM <tablename>
 GROUP BY album_id,id;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from YourTableName
group by album_id asc
```

try this..

Comment: First, it's not obvious what is OP's query. Second, `null` isn't a string value. It's a special value in DBMS. And `like` isn't a good way to deal with it