# Query- Error Code 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

Why do I get this error? While running the query? Why can't I group by Week?

Is the issue in the HAVING clause?

```
Select

CASE 

When 
min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) >= date(timestampadd(day,-7,now()))
and min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) <= date(timestampadd(day,0,now()))
Then 'Week 1'


When 
min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) >= date(timestampadd(day,-14,now()))   
and min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) < date(timestampadd(day,-7,now()))
Then  'Week 2'

When 
min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) >= date(timestampadd(day,-21,now()))   
and min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) < date(timestampadd(day,-14,now()))

Then  'Week 3'

When

min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) >= date(timestampadd(day,-29,now()))   
and min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) < date(timestampadd(day,-21,now()))
Then 'Week 4'

END AS WEEK

from

trip

WHERE

min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) > date(timestampadd(day,-28,now()))    
and min(date(trip.pick_up_time)) < date(timestampadd(day,0,now()))

group by Week HAVING Week is not NULL
```

Comment: group by Week HAVING Week is not NULL   - this is in the end

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Use this where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you GROUP BY with a CASE WHEN THEN alias name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096344/can-you-group-by-with-a-case-when-then-alias-name)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to use the whole CASE statement in the GROUP BY
like:

```
select 
  case when 1=1 then 1
       when 2=2 then 2
  end as result
from table
group by 
  case when 1=1 then 1
       when 2=2 then 2
  end
```

Comment: @learncode why? is it not working? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096344/can-you-group-by-with-a-case-when-then-alias-name

Comment: @learncode I understood that it will be a big query but that works

Comment: Please look at the answer