# Change value of another column when count <= 3

Tags: mysql

I have to make a query to display data for my gridview. I'm counting the amount of tickets for each ticket category but if the ticket count for that category is less than 3 I need to put that in an "other" category.

```
Select 
count(ticket.id) As 'Tickets',
if(count(ticket.id) <= 3, "Other",ticketCategoryName) As 'Ticket   Category'
FROM ds_tickets
GROUP BY 'Ticket Category
```

Instead of having something like this:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| TicketCategory | TicketCount |
+----------------+-------------+
| Category1      |           2 |
| Category2      |           3 |
| Category3      |           4 |
| Category4      |           5 |
+----------------+-------------+
```

I want it to be like:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| TicketCategory | TicketCount |
+----------------+-------------+
| Other          |           5 |
| Category3      |           4 |
| Category4      |           5 |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Try using CASE statement:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096344/can-you-group-by-with-a-case-when-then-alias-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CNT <= 3 THEN 'Other' ELSE TicketCategory END 'Ticket Category' ,
      SUM(CNT)
FROM( 
    SELECT  TicketCategory, COUNT(*) as CNT
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY  TicketCategory
)M
GROUP BY CASE WHEN CNT <= 3 THEN 'Other' ELSE TicketCategory END
```