# How can I add empty values in group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I add empty values in group by?

I have a query that is organized by ages:

But when the values have no results they are not in the select, I wanted to add 0 on all these CASE options.

My select for reference:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) < 4 THEN 'Menos de 4' 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5 a 9 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 10 AND 17 THEN '10 a 17 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN '18 a 24 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 25 AND 29 THEN '25 a 29 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30 a 39 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40 a 49 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50 a 59 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60 a 69 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) >= 70 THEN 'Maior que 70 Anos'
        ELSE 'SEM INFORMAÇÕES'  END , 
        COUNT(id)
        FROM pessoas GROUP BY DataNascimento
```

I want that when there is no value in the group the count id show 0

Comment: Perhaps `WHEN Year IS NULL OR DataNascimento IS NULL THEN 'NULL Anos'`.

Comment: Give the CASE statement an alias and GROUP BY that alias.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The group by DataNascimento will not work. You must group by the CASE and there you can include the else cases as well.

See answers to
[Can you GROUP BY with a CASE WHEN THEN alias name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096344/can-you-group-by-with-a-case-when-then-alias-name)

to add the count(0) for not found values the usage of union could work:

add to the end of your corrected statement (using case):

```
union select 'menos de 4', 0 from pessoas where
   DataNascimento not exists in 
      (select DataNascimento from pessoas where 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m   
       /%Y'),CURDATE()) < 4)

union select '5 a 9 Anos', 0 from pessoas where
   DataNascimento not exists in 
      (select DataNascimento from pessoas where 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m   
    /%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 ) 

union .....
```

Comment: for exemple: if this WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) < 4 THEN 'Menos de 4' dont have any person i want show 0 in id count

Comment: you can use UNION to add to the resultset the not found 0-values. Looks ugly, but should work: see the answer.