# how to group a column only if a certain status is true

Tags: sql, codeigniter, query-builder

```
$this->db->select('C.product_id,
                   A.customer_name,
                   A.contact_number,
                   A.email_id,
                   A.country_area_id,
                   A.sub_area_id,
                   A.building_no,
                   A.landmark,
                   A.alternative_number,
                   A.timing,
                   A.order_comments,
                   A.latitude,
                   A.longitude,
                   A.shipping_charge,
                   B.stock_item_stock,
                   C.bundle_status,
                   C.bundle_product_id');
        
$this->db->from('tbl_inventory_items as C');
        
$this->db->join('tbl_stock as B','B.stock_item_id=C.product_id and B.stock_status=0','left');
        
$this->db->join('tbl_inventory as A','C.inventory_id=A.inventory_id','left');
        
$this->db->where('C.inventory_id',$inv_ID);
```

in this, if C.bundle_status=3 i want to group C.bundle_product_id if not, no need to group

Comment: what if the result contain the the bundle_status= 3 and other status too?

Comment: there are other status too.

Comment: So same query we cannot do, then you need two queries.

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19096415/2275490

Answer (score 0):

USE this

```
$this->db->group_start()->where('C.bundle_status',3)->group_by('C.bundle_product_id )->group_end()
```

or create else condition with

```
->or_group_start()->where_not_in('C.bundle_status',3)->group_end()
```