# What is GROUP BY 1 in MySQL and what's the advantage?

Tags: mysql

I was viewing a question on stackoverflow and came across the following query. I was wondering what the `GROUP BY 1` was for.

```
SELECT
date(orderdate),
COUNT(id) AS num_orders
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY orderdate DESC
```

I know this query will generate a list of orders per day ordered from high to low. I would just like to understand the `GROUP BY`

#### In short

- What is `GROUP BY 1`
- Why wouldn't I use `GROUP BY orderdate`?

I mean either I should use column name or column position. Which method is preferable and why?

Comment: Group by 1 means date(orderdate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does SQL clause "GROUP BY 1" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392730/what-does-sql-clause-group-by-1-mean)

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I would also like to know the advantages of using this terminology. Does it still make my question a duplicate?

Comment: Hope this will answer your question: [Why do we use Group by 1 and Group by 1,2,3 in SQL query?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86609/why-do-we-use-group-by-1-and-group-by-1-2-3-in-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY 1` means, grouping of data on basis of first column. You can apply with `ORDER BY` too.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT date(orderdate),COUNT(id) AS num_orders
          ^^^^          ^^^^
          1            2
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1
```

In above query `GROUP BY 1` refers to the `first column` in `select` statement which is `date(orderdate)`.