# Insert data into table with relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access, relation

In Access have a simple table layout:

[image]

And I want to add data to *t_Bild*.
So I have created the query:

```
INSERT INTO t_Bild ( B_ID, M_ID, Dateiname, Datum )
VALUES (11, 8, "someName.png", DATE());
```

It works. But I need to get the max value for B_ID dynamically so the query inserts a new private key automatically. 
So I have modified the query:

```
INSERT INTO t_Bild ( B_ID, M_ID, Dateiname, Datum )
VALUES ((SELECT 1+ MAX(B_ID) FROM t_Bild), 8, "someName.png", DATE());
```

But the problem is that each time I run the query no data is inserted. I also do not get any error message back. 
I have checkt the query:

```
SELECT 1+ MAX(B_ID) FROM t_Bild;
```

And it works fine.

How can I achieve to add data to t_Bild with a valid private key?

Note: I am not able to set the private key to autonumber because I forgot to set it while modelling the database. Now Access does not allow me to set the private keys to autonumber anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the insert into...Select variant:

```
INSERT INTO t_Bild ( B_ID, M_ID, Dateiname, Datum )
   SELECT 1+ MAX(B_ID), 8, "someName.png", DATE()
   FROM t_Bild GROUP BY 2,3,4
```

Comment: Works fine! But why GROUP BY 2,3,4 ?

Comment: You cannot calculate an aggregate value like "Max" without a "Group by", and the 2,3,4 are another way to write: group by M_ID, Dateiname, Datum.
You can refer to this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392730/what-does-sql-clause-group-by-1-mean