# LARAVEL, ELOQUENT, SQL - groupBy 1

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, group-by

When I run the below SQL manually I get my expected results. I am trying to write the same query in Laravel's Eloquent and I get an error:

*SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1056 Can't group on 'aggregate' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `daily_menu` inner join `meals` on `daily_menu`.`id` = `meals`.`daily_menu_id` left join `fruits` on `fruits`.`meal_id` = `meals`.`id` where `lodge_id` = 1 group by 1)*

The original SQL Query that works:

```
SELECT
   d.id,
   SUM(IF(f.id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS fruit_count
FROM daily_menu d
  JOIN meals m
    ON d.id = m.daily_menu_id
  LEFT JOIN fruits f
    ON m.id = f.meal_id 
GROUP BY 1
```

My Laravel Eloquent Implementation:

```
$query = $query
    ->select("daily_menu.id", DB::raw("SUM(IF(fruits.id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS fruit_count"))
    ->join("meals", "daily_menu.id", "=", "meals.daily_menu_id")
    ->leftJoin("fruits", "fruits.meal_id", "=", "meals.id")
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $query
        ->select("daily_menu.id", DB::raw("SUM(IF(fruits.id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS fruit_count"))
        ->join("meals", "daily_menu.id", "=", "meals.daily_menu_id")
        ->leftJoin("fruits", "fruits.meal_id", "=", "meals.id")
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("daily_menu.id"));
```

I shouldn't have used 1 I should have used the proper column alias.
Related: [Can't fix this: "Cannot group by an aggregate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225875/cant-fix-this-cannot-group-by-an-aggregate)