# How can I get the count of distinct userID with some condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query for each distinct user and their count which logged In as Yes

```
Userid    loggedIn   
----    -----   
1   Yes       
1   yes       
1   No    
2   Yes         
2   No          
3   No          
4   yes        
5   yes        
1   No
```

Output Should be

```
Userid    Count   
----    -----   
1   2       
2   1          
3   0          
4   1        
5   1
```

Comment: `SELECT UserId, COUNT( CASE WHEN loggedIn = 'Yes' THEN 1 END ) AS "Count" FROM SomeTable GROUP BY UserId ORDER BY UserId;`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

```
with main as (

select distinct Userid from <table>
) 
select
    main.Userid,
    count(*) as total
from main
left join <table_name>
on main.Userid = <table_name>.Userid
and loggedIn = 'yes'
group by main.Userid
```

or

```
select
user_id,
sum(case when lower(loggedIn) = 'yes' then 1 end) as count_
from <table_name>
group by 1
```

Comment: Using `lower(loggedIn)` is unnecesary because SQL is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: Also, if `loggedIn <> 'yes'` then your `CASE` expression yields `0`, but `COUNT( 0 )` behaves the same as `COUNT( 1 )` - `COUNT` only considers `NULL` vs. non-`NULL`. I assume you're thinking of `SUM` instead.

Comment: `group by 1` <-- This is a bad practice in SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392730/what-does-sql-clause-group-by-1-mean - always use named columns.

Comment: it is not always necessary that it will accept both Yes or yes, depending on the column type etc. For the group by it is more of a personal choice.