# Confused by a Group by with a constant (SQL)

Tags: sql, group-by

I have seen a query on https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-case/
where within a GROUP BY a constant is used. Here ist the relevant excerpt:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN year = 'FR' THEN 'FR'
            WHEN year = 'SO' THEN 'SO'
            WHEN year = 'JR' THEN 'JR'
            WHEN year = 'SR' THEN 'SR'
            ELSE 'No Year Data' END AS year_group,
            COUNT(1) AS count
  FROM benn.college_football_players
 GROUP BY 1
```

Can someone explain to me why this is working? In my understanding only aggregate functions are allowed
in the SELECT clause (or functionally dependent columns - but there are no such columns in this case).
However, the CASE statement clearly is not an aggregating function.

Comment: Check this answer on an other exchange: [Why do we use Group by 1 and Group by 1,2,3 in SQL query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86609/why-do-we-use-group-by-1-and-group-by-1-2-3-in-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This clarifies the query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? `GROUP BY 1` isn't valid SQL standard syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does SQL clause "GROUP BY 1" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392730/what-does-sql-clause-group-by-1-mean)

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY 1` means `GROUP BY` the first item mentioned in SELECT. So in your case it means

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN year = 'FR' THEN 'FR'
            WHEN year = 'SO' THEN 'SO'
            WHEN year = 'JR' THEN 'JR'
            WHEN year = 'SR' THEN 'SR'
            ELSE 'No Year Data' END AS year_group,
            COUNT(1) AS count
  FROM benn.college_football_players
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN year = 'FR' THEN 'FR'
            WHEN year = 'SO' THEN 'SO'
            WHEN year = 'JR' THEN 'JR'
            WHEN year = 'SR' THEN 'SR'
            ELSE 'No Year Data' END
```

In your case `GROUP BY 1` saves a mess of repetitive code. It doesn't, however, save time: the query planner knows when items mentioned in `GROUP BY` clauses are identical to those in `SELECT` clauses.

Avoid this where possible in your own code, lest the next person to read it needs to ask "what is this GROUP BY 1?" on Stack Overflow, like you did.